# Generate random coordinates until correct

Tags: python, python-2.7

So basically I'm creating Snake (the game) in Python. I'm guessing you all know how it works, a snake, an apple - snake eats apple, grows bigger.

My code works well except for one issue, as the apple placement is random, it sometimes appears on the snake itself and becomes invisible as if eaten.

```
    def add_apple(self):
    # Place an apple in a random location on screen
    self.apple = (self.ui.random(WIDTH), self.ui.random(HEIGHT))
    a, b = self.apple
    self.ui.place(a, b, self.ui.FOOD)
```

My snake is a list:

```
    self.snake.append((self.x, self.y))
    self.ui.place(self.x, self.y, self.ui.SNAKE)

    # If apple is eaten, add another
    if self.apple == (self.x, self.y):
        self.add_apple()
    # For movement
    else:
        x, y = self.snake.pop(0)
        self.ui.place(x, y, self.ui.EMPTY)
```

So my quesstion is how I can make it so that if the apple's random location turns out to be on the snake, try again. I tried using a while loop in add_apple but the GUI would stop responding for some reason ( no error code)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We going to create new apple place until we found place that is not the snake

change

```py
def add_apple(self):
    # Place an apple in a random location on screen
    self.apple = (self.ui.random(WIDTH), self.ui.random(HEIGHT))
    a, b = self.apple
    self.ui.place(a, b, self.ui.FOOD)
```

into this:

```py
def add_apple(self):
    # Place an apple in a random location on screen
    self.apple = (self.ui.random(WIDTH), self.ui.random(HEIGHT))
    while self.apple in self.snake:
        self.apple = (self.ui.random(WIDTH), self.ui.random(HEIGHT))
    a, b = self.apple
    self.ui.place(a, b, self.ui.FOOD)
```

if you want to make it faster, you can do it as:

```py
from random import choice
def add_apple(self):
    # Place an apple in a random location on screen
    x_snakes = [i[0] for i in self.snake] # all snake x posisions
    y_snakes = [i[1] for i in self.snake] # all sanke y posisions
    x_not_snake = [i for i in range(WIDTH) if i not in x_snake] # all the posision that the snake is not in the x cordinate
    y_not_snake = [i for i in range(HEIGHT) if i not in y_snake] # same for y
    self.apple = (choice(x_not_snake), choice(y_not_snake)) # randomly get one
    a, b = self.apple
    self.ui.place(a, b, self.ui.FOOD)
```

this will works much better for end game state, because it will find a random place for sure every `random` call